# OpenGL ES object rotation around Z axis

Tags: ios, opengl-es, rotation, cocos3d

I have an object on my screen which is presented rotated and panned,
But i have 2 problems regarding the z axis rotations. It's a bit tricky to explain so i uploaded 2 videos to describe each problem.

1) [Reverse rotation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cr-mqM6rtrc&feature=youtu.be) : After rotating the object around the x axis, the z rotations are being reversed and as it should be.

2) [Wrong Z axis rotation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUiyugt9uD0) : Again, After rotating the object around the x axis, i'm trying to rotate the object around the z axis and the rotation results in a different axis rotations.

I do believe the video's describe the problems well.

**EDIT: UPDATE #1**

Ok, i thought i found the solution, which was rotating only the camera around the Z axis,
And perform X and Y rotations on the model itself. This seemed to be good, But of course it led to a new problem described in this [**VIDEO**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgpBe0TsVT0) (it's in the 23'd second, the rest is to show how it is being done).

The reason this is happening is the axis system of the object is being rotated and when i am doing a Z axis rotation followed by a X or Y axis rotations, The results are wrong.

I just don't know how to rotate the object alone from the axis system, so that the rotations will be done correctly.

Now, for the code part:

The rendering function:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
    ...

    CC3GLMatrix *projection = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
    float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
    [projection populateFromFrustumLeft:-2 andRight:2 andBottom:-h/2 andTop:h/2 andNear:4 andFar:100];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);

    [modelView populateFromTranslation:_currentPan];
    [modelView rotateBy:_currentRotation];
    [modelView rotateByZ:zRotationEnd];

    glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);
    ...        
}
```

X and Y rotations:

```
- (void) rotateAroundX:(float) x andY:(float) y newRotate:(BOOL) isNewRotate
{
    if (isNewRotate) {
        rotationStart = CC3VectorMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    int rotationDirection = ceil(zRotationEnd/90);
    if (rotationDirection % 4 == 2 || rotationDirection % 4 == 3) {
        rotationEnd.x = rotationEnd.x - (x-rotationStart.x);
        rotationEnd.y = rotationEnd.y - (y-rotationStart.y);
    } else {
        rotationEnd.x = rotationEnd.x + (x-rotationStart.x);
        rotationEnd.y = rotationEnd.y + (y-rotationStart.y);
    }

    rotationStart.x = x;
    rotationStart.y = y;

    _currentRotation = CC3VectorMake(rotationEnd.y, rotationEnd.x, 0);
    NSLog(@"Current x is: %f y is: %f z is: %f",_currentRotation.x,_currentRotation.y,zRotationEnd);
}
```

And the relevant calling part:

```
if(sender.numberOfTouches == 1)
    {
        BOOL started = false;
        CGPoint rotation = [sender translationInView:sender.view];
        float x = rotation.x;
        float y = rotation.y;
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
            started = true;
        }
        [self.glView rotateAroundX:x andY:y newRotate:started];
    }
```

The Z rotation function:

```
- (void) rotateAroundZ:(float) z newRotate:(BOOL) isNewRotate
{
    if (isNewRotate) {
        zRotationStart = 0;
    }
    zRotationEnd = zRotationEnd - (z - zRotationStart);
    zRotationStart = z;
}
```

And the relevant calling part:

```
- (IBAction)rotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    BOOL started = false;
    float rotation = RadiansToDegrees([sender rotation]);
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        started = true;
    }
    [self.glView rotateAroundZ:rotation newRotate:started];
    NSLog(@"Rotation %f", rotation);
}
```

The shader:

```
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;

varying vec4 DestinationColor;

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void) {
    DestinationColor = SourceColor;
    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Simple rotations.

This is the easiest way to rotate an object based on touch movement. Here is example

```
pseudocode:

Matrix.setIdentity(modelMatrix);

... do other translations here ...

Matrix.rotateX(totalYMovement);
Matrix.rotateY(totalXMovement);
```

This is done every frame.

To rotate an object up or down, we rotate it around the X-axis, and to rotate an object left or right, we rotate it around the Y axis. We could also rotate an object around the Z axis if we wanted it to spin around.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.learnopengles.com/rotating-an-object-with-touch-events/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to implement a [gimbal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal).

Although you seem to be only using Cocos3D for the basic data math structures, have a look at [this post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/rotating-behaviour-with-swipe-gesture/#post-412564), which describes creating a gimbal in Cocos3D, and which might help point you in the right direction.

Creating a gimbal is easier to implement using nested structural objects (`CC3Node` in Cocos3D) that match the structure of a gimbal, instead of trying to apply consecutive rotations to a single matrix. But, with a little algorithmic analysis and experimentation, you may be able to extract the resulting matrix math and implement it on a single matrix.

Remember that a successful gimbal requires that the rotations be performed in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is coming because you are rotating around x,y and z at the same time. The problem is that your z-axis rotation is around the z axis as defined by the object when its model matrix is identity.

The easiest way to solve this is with a compound matrix multiply.  Essentially by multiplying matrices together you are specifying the order of the operations performed.

In your case you want to apply the "x-y" animation as you already do.  You THEN want to perform your z-axis rotation.

So something like the following: (I've never written an cocos3d code so this is based on a quick search through the docs, there may be typos).

```
CC3GLMatrix* rotationXY = [CC3GLMatrix identity];
[rotationXY rotateBy: _currentRotation];

CC3GLMatrix* rotationZ  = [CC3GLMatrix rotateByZ: zRotationEnd];

[rotationXY multiplyByMatrix: rotationZ];
```

This should give you your correct model matrix.  Finally you need to multiply your view (camera) matrix in:

```
[rotationXY multiplyByMatrix: view];
[CC3GLMatrix copyMatrix: rotationXY into: modelView];
```

You now should be seeing the behaviour you expect.